# Any way to silence the UIDevice setOrientation warning?

Tags: iphone, warnings, uidevice, setorientation

Anyone have a simple way to silence the undocumented UIDevice setOrientation warning?

I found this [piece of code](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5440-silent-uipickerview.html) that silences the undocumented UIPickerView setSoundsEnabled warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just declare the method in a category in the `.h` or `.m` file of wherever you use it:

```
@interface UIDevice (MyPrivateNameThatAppleWouldNeverUseGoesHere)
- (void) setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
@end
```

Comment: … and hope that Apple doesn't use the "(private)" category on UIDevice. I'd probably call it "(MyUndocumentedMethods)" or something.

Comment: Cool -- works great!  What's the category feature originally designed for?

Comment: It is meant for extending the functionality of a class.  BJ Homer is right… you should not use (private).  I will change in the code

Comment: To do private method declarations, you can say `@interface UIDevice ()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just subscribe to the orientation notifications?  They are supported and work at the same time.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Comment: Heh, I need to change the orientation, not listen to it.  The problem stems from having one orientable view in the middle of a chain of navigation.  When I leave the rotated view for the view that can only take the portrait orientation I have to force the change because unless there is an orientation change the upcoming view that only can be in portrait mode will be rotated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to add your controller to the window view directly. It's a bit boring but it works well ! http://www.geckogeek.fr/iphone-forcer-le-mode-landscape-ou-portrait-en-cours-dexecution.html :-)

Comment: That looks really useful. do you know of english version? i'd hate to use google translate for this...